# Prove that every convex region is simply connected

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Prove that every convex region is simply connected

Could anyone help?

Comment: You have to prove two things: that it's path connected, and that every continuous image of $S^1$ can be shrunk to a point (or some equivalent statement). Can you at least do the first?

Comment: Is it true that a convex region is star-like? If this is true, it could help.

Comment: In, fact, this is true, once every point can be joined by a segment to another one. So, choose one and use this point to construct a homotopy. I guess this could wortk.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Choose a point $z_0\in R$ (which denotes the region). Choosing any other point $z\in R$, the segment joining these two is contained in $R$, by convexity. Then, you are able to construct a linear contraction of $R$ to this $z_0$:

$$C:[0,1]\times R\rightarrow R$$
$$(t,z)\mapsto z_0+t(z-z_0)$$

Therefore, any closed path $\gamma:\mathbb{S}^1\rightarrow R$ can be shrunken to $z_0$ by composing the path with the contraction.

Comment: this only shows contractible correct? @Chill2Macht

Comment: ?? is that correct

Comment: for path connected, if $a,b \in R$ then take $\gamma(t):=(1-t)a+tb$ for $t \in [0,1]$? and show $\vert \gamma \vert \leq 1$?

Comment: @HossienSahebjame I don't understand the question? I haven't done / thought about algebraic topology in ages / am very rusty, but I thought conractible implies simply connected? I.e. the proof might be "overkill" in showing a condition stronger than simply connected, but still correct? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1707132/show-that-a-contractible-space-is-simply-connected I don't remember why I edited this answer, but I'm guessing for clearer formatting. The last line seems to allude to a more complete proof that "conractible $\implies$ simply conneced" -- really I'm not 100% sure.